# two class CSS not picking up both classes

Tags: css, class

Hi I'm following a tutorial. As far as I can see I have written exactly the same thing in my code but it is behaving differently.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
}

.panel {
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0.5;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panel.active {
  flex: 5;
}

.panel.active h3 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel active" style="background-image: url('./vincent-guth-uhoILl3HUZM-unsplash.jpg')">
      <h3>Beautiful Sky</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('./juskteez-vu-TIrXot28Znc-unsplash.jpg')">
      <h3>Incredible sky</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('./casey-horner-fsJB3KT2rj8-unsplash.jpg')">
      <h3>Northern Lights</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('./vincent-guth-uhoILl3HUZM-unsplash.jpg')">
      <h3>Northern Lights</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('./vincent-guth-uhoILl3HUZM-unsplash.jpg')">
      <h3>Beautiful Sky</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

but on the screen the panel that's active loses all the css from the panel class instead of using both. Any ideas why this might be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works but the problem is you are using 100% size of your images so its looks like this:

**I added border to demonstrate**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
}

.panel {
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0.5;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
  border: red 2px solid;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panel.active {
  flex: 5;
}

.panel.active h3 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel active" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/266/200/300')">
      <h3>Beautiful Sky</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/230/200/300')">
      <h3>Incredible sky</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/217/200/300')">
      <h3>Northern Lights</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/227/200/300')">
      <h3>Northern Lights</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/137/200/300')">
      <h3>Beautiful Sky</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The solution is using **background-size: cover;** instead

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
}

.panel {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0.5;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
  border: red 2px solid;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panel.active {
  flex: 5;
}

.panel.active h3 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel active" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/266/200/300')">
      <h3>Beautiful Sky</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/230/200/300')">
      <h3>Incredible sky</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/217/200/300')">
      <h3>Northern Lights</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/227/200/300')">
      <h3>Northern Lights</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/137/200/300')">
      <h3>Beautiful Sky</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, I'm still not sure why but perhaps it will make more sense in time and with practise!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change value of background-size property to cover (background-size: cover). I think this is what you need

Comment: reproducible code

Answer (score -1):

I ran your code in codepen. I only changed the background-images to colors since the were loaded locally. It is behaving as it should, the panel active div displaying everything defined in the panel class aswell. What are you missing?

https://codepen.io/wischn/pen/OJwOQxp

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
}

.panel {
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0.5;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
 position: absolute; 
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panel.active {
  flex: 5;
}

.panel.active h3 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Mine was not showing the rounded corners on the edge of the active image (so lost border radius), didn't show the text and was the wrong size. Another commenter said put background-size to cover. I've done this and now it's working. However the one in the tutorial works as yours did. So I have a solution, just don't understand it yet!